# Displaying an image within a gridview based on a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

My first issue is that my image is not displaying, code is as follows;

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Image">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Images\green_tick.jpg"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The second is that I am not sure how to begin to display an image based on the variable (a bool) under the binding `{Binding ExtractionCompleted}`

Thanks.

Comment: To bind an image to the boolean value you need to use a value converter. See http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Not necessarily you can use {Binding ExtractionCompleted} Value="true" in the DataTemplate->Resources->Style->Triggers->DataTriggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via a `DataTrigger`.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Image">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Images\green_tick.jpg">
                <Image.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExtractionCompleted}" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

As for your image, make sure the `BuildAction` is set to `Resource`. You can do this by checking the Properties of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyImageTemplate">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Value}" Height="20"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Define an unbound column:

XAML:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="MyTempField" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" UnboundType="Object" />
```

Then comes the handling part of GridControl.CustomUnboundColumnData event to set a value:

```
private void grid_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, GridColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.IsGetData)
        {
            if (((NewTestData)((GridControl)sender).GetRowByListIndex(e.ListSourceRowIndex)).Number1 > 10)
                e.Value = "demo.gif";
            else
                e.Value = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 for providing a poor, WinForms style answer to a WPF question... you should learn how to use WPF correctly before you try giving advice on how to use it. The WPF way is to use either a `Trigger` or a `Converter` if there are more than two different images to display.

Comment: I dont understand the downvote but I have used the same method in WPF in the past and it has worked. I think my answer provided clear steps on how to tackle this step by step.

Comment: Your answer is clearly influenced by your previous experience with WinForms. Whether it has the same end result or not is a moot point. That is *not* how to achieve the desired result in WPF. Therefore... down vote. It is bad practice to advise that other users should follow your WinForms styled answer when writing WPF.